# Why is WolframAlpha saying that two equal expressions are not equal?

Tags: complex-integration

I am trying to solve the following integral:
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\int \sin(\alpha t)\exp(-i\alpha t)\, \text{dt}.
\end{equation}
Using the exponential form of $\sin(\alpha t)$, the integral becomes
\begin{equation}\label{pet}
\int \frac{1}{2i}\big{(}\exp(i(\alpha-w)t)-\exp(-i(\alpha+w)t)\big{)}\,\text{dt} = \frac{1}{2i}\Big{(}\frac{1}{i(\alpha-w)}\exp(i(\alpha-w)t)+\frac{1}{i(\alpha+w)}\exp(-i(\alpha+w)t)\Big{)}\;\;(+\text{ constant}).
\end{equation}
When I input Eq. (2) into WolframAlpha, it returns True. If I rearrange the right-hand side of Eq. (2) by taking out $\frac{1}{i}$, I get
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2i}\Big{(}\frac{1}{i(\alpha-w)}\exp(i(\alpha-w)t)+\frac{1}{i(\alpha+w)}\exp(-i(\alpha+w)t)\Big{)} = -\frac{1}{2}\Big{(}\frac{1}{(\alpha-w)}\exp(i(\alpha-w)t)+\frac{1}{(\alpha+w)}\exp(-i(\alpha+w)t)\Big{)}.
\end{equation}
If I input Eq. (3) into WolframAlpha, it also returns True.
However, when I enter the left-hand side of Eq. (2), i.e., the integral, equated with the new rearrangement from Eq. (3) as follows
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{2i}\big{(}\exp(i(\alpha-w)t)-\exp(-i(\alpha+w)t)\big{)}\,\text{dt} = -\frac{1}{2}\Big{(}\frac{1}{(\alpha-w)}\exp(i(\alpha-w)t)+\frac{1}{(\alpha+w)}\exp(-i(\alpha+w)t)\Big{)}\;\;(+\text{ constant}),
\end{equation}
WolframAlpha returns False.
I don't understand how this is possible. Surely, if $a = b \text{ and } b = c$, it must follow that $a = c$ by transitivity.

Here is the the code I typed directly into WolframAlpha:

- For Eq. (2): "is integral(sin(at)exp(-iwt)) = 1/(2i)(1/(i(a-w))exp(i(a-w)t)+1/(i(a+w))exp(-i(a+w)t))". This returns True.
- For Eq. (3): "is 1/(2i)(1/(i(a-w))exp(i(a-w)t)+1/(i(a+w))exp(-i(a+w)t)) = -1/2(1/(a-w)exp(i(a-w)t)+1/(a+w)exp(-i(a+w)t))". This also returns True.
- For Eq. (4): "is integral(sin(at)exp(-iwt)) = -1/2(1/(a-w)exp(i(a-w)t)+1/(a+w)exp(-i(a+w)t))". This returns False.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Left part may have constant of integration. You should give your WolframAlpha code for check.

Comment: Rather than asking if $f=g$ where $f$ and $g$ are two results from (indefinite) integration, you should ask if $f-g$ is a constant.